# Как присвоить индекс переменной A в качестве значения переменной B? PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В данном коде мы видим общий цикл в котором есть 2 переменные `$sku` и две переменные `$product_mod`. Первая пара выводит информацию продукта "Кофе", а вторая пара выводит информацию добавки к продукту "Сахар". 
Задача: для переменной `$product_mod`, которая является добавкой "Сахар" с индексом 1 (второй объект в общем цикле) получить значение - индекс первого продукта. Тем самым мы укажем, что сахар - это дополнение к кофе.

В данном случае переменная `$product_mod[] = '';` должна получить номер индекса переменной `$sku[] = $product->get_sku();`

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
    $product = $item->get_product();

    $sku[] = $product->get_sku();
    $product_mod[] = NULL;

    $as = $item->get_meta('Мета ключ');
    if( strpos( $as, 'Значение ключа' ) !== false ) {
        $sku[] = '20001';
        $product_mod[] = '';
    }
}
```

Для наглядности сейчас код с помощью `print_r` выводит:

```
&sku[0]=10001 // Первый продукт в цикле
&sku[1]=30001 // Второй продукт в цикле с необходимой переменной
&product_mod[1]=1 // Индекс свой, а нужно с первого продукта
```

Добиться пытаюсь этого:

```
&sku[0]=10001 // Первый продукт в цикле
&sku[1]=30001 // Второй продукт в цикле с необходимой переменной
&product_mod[1]=0 // Продукт с индексом 1 имеет значение 0 (индекс первого продукта)
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: Бррр.. непонятно :) Вы хотите получить на выходе массив идентификаторов товаров у которых мета-ключ равен определенному значению?

Comment: На самом деле, в коде видно, что идёт проверка значений определённого мета ключа. И если находит совпадение, то ему назначаются переменные `&sku` и `&product_mod`. (В данном случае это не имеет большого значения). Достаточно взглянуть на вывод `print_r`. А задание - взять индекс переменной и сделать его значением другой переменной.